# Catch screen lock/unlock events in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, winlogon

Is there a way to catch screen lock/unlock events in Windows 10? I found this article: [Winlogon Notification Packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/en-en/library/windows/desktop/aa380545(v=vs.85).aspx), but it seems to be old as hell - it has a note in a header, that ***Event Handler Function Prototype*** and ***WLX_NOTIFICATION_INFO*** are not supported as of Windows Server 2008/Windows Vista.
OK, what to do then? Are there other approaches via native Win32API or .NET?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, where is the current documentation?